# ArrayFormula + multiple VLOOKUP/ Query/ Filter results + Transpose

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So I'm trying to use this function over Google Sheets, but this applies only over the first row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Glide App Users'!D2:D,'Glide App Users'!B2:B=N2:N)))
```

What am I doing wrong and how can this be fixed/ workedarounded?

Expected to get all matching values (rows) from 'Glide App Users' sheet, and write them transposely into my sheet according to the matching values between N2:N and 'Glide App Users'!D2:D

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the below.
Nesty - but working

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N2:N, 
       {SORT(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("'Glide App Users'!B2:B"&COUNTA('Glide App Users'!B2:B)+1))), 
         SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE('Glide App Users'!B2:D), 
        "SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col3", 0), "OFFSET 1", 0)), 
        "♦"&QUERY(UNIQUE('Glide App Users'!B2:D), 
         "SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1 
         PIVOT Col3 LIMIT 0", 0), )) ,,999^99))), "♦")}, {2,3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MAP, like this:

```
=MAP(N2:N,LAMBDA(search_key,TOROW(FILTER('Glide App Users'!D2:D,'Glide App Users'!B2:B=search_key))))
```